# Set Ruby variable in Java Script if-else block

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables

I have this java script block of code :

```
if(cond1){
  <% @user_status = "new" %>
} else if(cond2){
  <% @user_status = "active" %>
} else if(cond3){
  <% @user_status = "inactive" %>
} else{
  <% @user_status = "pending" %>
}
```

`url = "<%= users_with_status_path(:user_status => @user_status) %>";`

I am using this variable `@user_status` to do an AJAX call. The problem is that irrespective of the condition, this variable is always set to "pending". Why would it be?

Comment: You do realize that your ruby variables are long gone when it is time for this JS gets to be executed?

Comment: Hint: look at the javascript code that will be generated from this.

Comment: You will have to assign regular JS variables and do your url building in javascript only. No ruby for you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign values to a ruby variable inside javascript block.

You need to create javascript variables .

```
<script>

var status = ''
if(cond1){
  status = "new"
} else if(cond2){
 status = "active" 
} else if(cond3){
status = "inactive" 
} else{
status = "pending" 
}

url = "/user status path?user_status="+status;

you ajax call
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I did.